# Cat.js automation framework issue do get it running after installation

Tags: javascript

dear stackoverfellows,

actually iam testing a new framework for cross device testing, its name is cat.js. is relative new, so i didnt found any answers on google. i will ask you.

consider my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TestCase1 Cat.jazz</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--script src="app.js"></script-->

     <!--
      @[scrap
          @@import[
              /cat/lib/cat.js
          ]

      ]@
    -->

</head>
<body>

    <div id="catjsId0" onclick="this.style.color='red'; this.innerHTML+= '[I was clicked!]'">
        CAT JS HELLO CAPS LOCK!!!111
    </div>

    <div id="catjsId1" onclick="this.style.color='blue'; this.innerHTML+= '[I was clicked!]'">
        CAT JS HELLO CAPS LOCK!!!111
    </div>

    <div id="catjsId2" onclick="this.style.color='green'; this.innerHTML+= '[I was clicked!]'">
        CAT JS HELLO CAPS LOCK!!!111
    </div>

    <div id="catjsId3" onclick="this.style.color='yellow'; this.innerHTML+= '[I was clicked!]'">
        CAT JS HELLO CAPS LOCK!!!111
    </div>

    <!--
      @[scrap
          @@name clickBtn0
          @@context $
          @@embed true
          @@log "Button 0 is clicked"
          @@assert ok($("#catjsId0"), "messageText")
          @@code $("#catjsId0").click()
      ]@
    -->

    <!--
      @[scrap
          @@name clickBtn123
          @@context $
          @@embed true
          @@log "Rest Buttons clicked"
          @@assert ok($("#catjsId1"), "messageText2")
          @@code $("#catjsId1").click()
          @@code $("#catjsId2").click()
          @@code $("#catjsId3").click()
      ]@
    -->

</body>
</html>
```

when i do the terminal line `catcli -cabs` to clearBuildServer and goto localhost:8089, i get the cat.js layer, but an huge error too. the terminal output is

```
[e629a0af-ab7b-4368-9238-0203c0e87077] ======== Test Start  ========
[e629a0af-ab7b-4368-9238-0203c0e87077] ✖Test generalJSError Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined  ;file:  http://localhost:8089/cat/lib/cat.js  ;line:  1243  ;column: 51  ;error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
[e629a0af-ab7b-4368-9238-0203c0e87077] ✖Test generalJSError Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input  ;file:  http://localhost:8089/  ;line:  0  ;column: 0  ;error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

what makes me really feel bad about this, that i worked the whole day on it and had it running as intend. but after installing the mobilerunner.js that is suggestet to test cross-device, suddenly all broke. Even after creating a complete new project couldnt solve my problem. So i politly ask the audience, does anyone of you guys know the error and solved it.

with best regards